# Custom Post Type to Plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

Recently Themeforest Ask all the new developers to Add Custom Post Type Throught Plugin.. My question is
I have testimonial.php Custom Post Type With Meta Boxes

```
<?php
    function register_testimonial() {

        $labels = array(
            'name' => 'Testimonial',
            'singular_name' => 'Testimonial',
            'add_new' => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New testimonial',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Testimonial',
            'new_item' => 'New Testimonial',
            'view_item' => 'View Testimonial',
            'search_items' => 'Search Testimonial',
            'not_found' => 'No Testimonial found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Testimonial found in Trash',
            'menu_name' => 'Testimonial',
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-testimonial',
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'can_export' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post'
        );

        register_post_type( 'testimonial', $args );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'register_testimonial' );


    add_action( 'admin_init', 'testimonial_admin' );
    function testimonial_admin() {
        add_meta_box( 'testimonial_meta_box',
            'Testimonial Details',
            'display_testimonial_meta_box',
            'testimonial', 'normal', 'high'
        );
    }
    function register_post_assets(){

    }
    add_action('admin_init', 'register_post_assets', 1);


    function display_testimonial_meta_box( $testimonial ) {
        // Retrieve current name of the Name and testimonial Rating based on review ID
        $WEBSITE_Name = esc_html( get_post_meta( $testimonial->ID, 'WEBSITE_Name', true ) );
        $WEBSITE_URL = esc_html( get_post_meta( $testimonial->ID, 'WEBSITE_URL', true ) );
        ?>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%">WEBSITE Name : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="WEBSITE_Name" value="<?php echo $WEBSITE_Name; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%">WEBSITE URL : </td>
        <td><input type="url" name="WEBSITE_URL" value="<?php echo $WEBSITE_URL; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
    }

    add_action( 'save_post', 'add_testimonial_fields', 10, 2 );

    function add_testimonial_fields( $testimonial_id, $testimonial ) {
        // Check post type for testimonial reviews
        if ( $testimonial->post_type == 'testimonial' ) {
            // Store data in post meta table if present in post data
            if ( isset( $_POST['WEBSITE_Name'] ) && $_POST['WEBSITE_Name'] != '' ) {
                update_post_meta( $testimonial_id, 'WEBSITE_Name', $_POST['WEBSITE_Name'] );
            }
            if ( isset( $_POST['WEBSITE_URL'] ) && $_POST['WEBSITE_URL'] != '' ) {
                update_post_meta( $testimonial_id, 'WEBSITE_URL', $_POST['WEBSITE_URL'] );
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

How can i create Plugin of This???

Comment: Read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin and this: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/header-requirements/

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Answer (score 1):

i agree with the other answers, but neither addressed flushing the re-write rules.  If you don't add this, it will confuse your users when they activate the plugin and still can't access the custom postypes on the front.

The other problem you're going to have is that LOTS of people will use testimonials so if your clients load a plugin that uses testimonials and is using the same postype or if they were previously using another plugin that had a CPT testimonials, there will be conflicts.

It is better if you prefix your identifier with a short namespace that identifies your plugin, theme or website that implements the custom post type (instead of testimonials, say  "haroon_testimonials"  to ensure no one else will be using your post type in their systems.

Then to address post links on the front (so they see www.example.com/testimoinals/1 instead of www.example.com/haroon-testimonials/1
you'll need to use a re-write back to testimonials:

```
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'locations'),
```

Here is a sample code i use:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package rt_create_cpt
 * @version 1.0
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Post Creation by RT
Description: A Plugin to create CPT 
Author: RT, Inc
Version: 3.4
Author URI: http://
*/

add_action( 'init', 'rt_custom_post' );
function rt_custom_post() {
  register_post_type( 'rt_locations',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Locations' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Location' ),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New Location', 'Location'),
        'add_new_item' => __("Add New Location"),
        'edit_item' => __("Edit This Location"),
        'new_item' => __("New Location"),
        'view_item' => __("View Location"),
        'search_items' => __("Search in Locations"),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __("Used for image for this Location"),
        'featured_image' => __("Location Image"),
        'set_featured_image' => __("Set Location Image"),
        'remove_featured_image' => __("Remove Location Image"),
        'use_featured_image' => __("Use Location Image"),
        'not_found' =>  __('No Locations'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Locations found in Trash')

      ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
       'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-store',
    'supports' => array('title','author','thumbnail','editor'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'locations'),
    )
  );
}


function rt_rewrite_flush() {
    // First, we "add" the custom post type via the above written function.
    // Note: "add" is written with quotes, as CPTs don't get added to the DB,
    // They are only referenced in the post_type column with a post entry, 
    // when you add a post of this CPT.
    rt_custom_post();

    // ATTENTION: This is *only* done during plugin activation hook in this example!
    // You should *NEVER EVER* do this on every page load!!
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'rt_rewrite_flush' );

?>
```

you'll just want to put your code function in and then change the rewrite rule to match your code!

Comment: did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this out of your theme into a new folder (The plugin folder) and add the next lines to the beginning of your code:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: My Plugin Name
* Plugin URI: http://mypluginuri.com/
* Description: A brief description about your plugin.
* Version: 1.0 or whatever version of the plugin (pretty self explanatory)
* Author: Plugin Author's Name
* Author URI: Author's website
* License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL12
*/
```

Now you should name this file and your folder with the same name like:

`…/plugins/haroon-register-testimonial/haroon-register-testimonial.php`

Notice that I added "haroon-" prefix at the beginning of the folder and filename in order to make it's name unique, this is needed to work properly with other plugins by avoiding repeated names.

Now you should add a readme.txt to inform users about any updates and the usage of your plugin. Is not needed but recommended.

That's it! now you have a plugin!

Read more on the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and [Here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin)

I think the 2nd create a custom post type as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom post type plugin of your choice and you have to follow the steps in order to create the successful plugin of your choice.

**1. Step One:**

You have to create a folder under the `wp-content->plugins->YOUR PLUGIN FOLDER`.

(E.g) - In Our Exapmple we are going to create the plugin called `Destination_Category`

Folder Structure: `wp-content->plugins->Destination_Category`.

**2. Step Two:**

Inside that folder you have to create the file structure as follows.

1. css(folder)
2. images(folder)
3. index.php

**3. Step Three:**

Open up the index.php and you have to add the copyrights and descriptions for the plugin.

In our example we are going to create as Destination Category.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Destination Category
Description: This plugin is used for the creation of the Custom Category for the Wordpress Destination Post type and it allows you to link the Category and the Sub Category using this plugin.
Version: 1.0
Author: Naresh Kumar.P
Email: nareshkumar.palani@gmail.com
License: NKPDC007
*/
?>
```

After creating this Structure you can see the plugin in the `Plugins` Menu at the WordPress Dashboard. You can see the Plugin Name, Description, Email and all the other details that you have provided.

**4. Step Four:**

In addition to the Step Three you have to `register the custom post type` with the code available for it and you are created with the plugin that you need.

```
//Creation of custom post type(Start)
add_action( 'init', 'create_destination_category' );
function create_destination_category() 
{
  $args = array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Destination Categories',
                'singular_name' => 'Destination Category',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Destination Category',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Destination Category',
                'new_item' => 'New Destination Category',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Destination Category',
                'search_items' => 'Search Destination Category',
                'not_found' => 'No Destination Categories found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Destination Category found in Trash',            
            ),           
            'menu_position' => 15,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),            
            'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/logo.png', __FILE__ ),
            'public' => true          
         );
         register_post_type( 'destination_category',$args);         
 }//Creation of custom post type(End)
```

And one more step to go and that is you are now to activate the plugin that you have created and you will be getting the message as `Your plugin is successfully activated` and thus your plugin is successfully created.

And onto the whole the entire index.php will look like the below code.

**index.php**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Destination Category
Description: This plugin is used for the creation of the Custom Category for the Wordpress Destination Post type and it allows you to link the Category and the Sub Category using this plugin.
Version: 1.0
Author: Naresh Kumar.P
Email: nareshkumar.palani@gmail.com
License: NKPDC007
*/

//Creation of custom post type(Start)
add_action( 'init', 'create_destination_category' );
function create_destination_category() 
{
  $args = array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Destination Categories',
                'singular_name' => 'Destination Category',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Destination Category',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Destination Category',
                'new_item' => 'New Destination Category',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Destination Category',
                'search_items' => 'Search Destination Category',
                'not_found' => 'No Destination Categories found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Destination Category found in Trash',            
            ),           
            'menu_position' => 15,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),            
            'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/logo.png', __FILE__ ),
            'public' => true          
         );
         register_post_type( 'destination_category',$args);         
 }//Creation of custom post type(End)   
?>
```